# PHP: Why is there an additional blank line of output from a while loop?

Tags: php, while-loop

Here is the PHP code:

```
$i = "1";
while ($i <= 13) {
    echo "i is: $i" . "\n";
    $i++;
}
```

This is the output from the command line on Linux Bash shell:

```
i is: 1
i is: 2
i is: 3
i is: 4
i is: 5
i is: 6
i is: 7
i is: 8
i is: 9
i is: 10
i is: 11
i is: 12
i is: 13

$
```

Why is the an empty blank line after 13 and before the prompt? I'm setting the while loop to be less than or equal to 13. Shouldn't it stop there? How do I control this so it finishing 13 and doesn't do another loop through? Or is there a better approach to this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For scripts with PHP only, omit the last `?>`

Contrary to what all other answers say, this is probably the cause.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot confirm that. Try a die at the end and you'll see this output:

```
i is: 1
i is: 2
i is: 3
i is: 4
i is: 5
i is: 6
i is: 7
i is: 8
i is: 9
i is: 10
i is: 11
i is: 12
i is: 13
$
```

It's because you probably have an additional new line after the `?>`

Comment: It's not a reason in this case.

Comment: Why the downvote, it's not the new line after 13 he wonders about, but the empty line before the ```$```.

Comment: @CORRUPT what makes you think that?

Comment: I agree with @steffen here, new lines after the last `?>` is most likely OPs problem.

Answer (score 1):

The extra empty line is caused by the `"\n"` of your last `echo "i is: $i" . "\n";` print out.

It works like this:

```
i is: 1\n
i is: 2\n
i is: 3\n
i is: 4\n
i is: 5\n
i is: 6\n
i is: 7\n
i is: 8\n
i is: 9\n
i is: 10\n
i is: 11\n
i is: 12\n
i is: 13\n
```

and each of the

```
i is: 1\n
```

is displayed as

```
i is: 1

$
```

`\n` puts the current cursor to the newline position, ready to append the next character.
Try `echo "\n" . "i is: $i" ;` to understand better.

Comment: @CORRUPT What do you mean?

Comment: it seems like @steffen might be correct as well.
could it be platform dependent?

Answer (score 1):

Cause of the `\n` it reaches 13 and then adds a new line and then it ends.

Answer (score 0):

You have the last element with \n, you could check if is the last element.
Try this:

```
$i = "1";
while ($i <= 13) {
    if($i==13)
        echo "i is: $i";
    else
        echo "i is: $i" . "\n";
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `\n` is adds another line. One way you can prevent is by checking that it's the last member if the loop

```
$i = "1";
while ($i <= 13) {
    echo "i is: $i";
    if ($i != 13)
        echo "\n";
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*The  empty line appearing   by the "\n"*

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to print out the numbers you may use a range:

```
echo 'i is: '. implode("\ni is: ", range(1,13));
```